# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at C:/.../Chrome/Application/chrome.exe with ChromeDriver Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Bit of a Python newbie here...

Windows 7 x64 and Python 3.7

I have installed Selenium and the Chrome Webdriver. I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='C:/python/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

I'm getting:

```
\python\python.exe C:/py/defectURLS/app.py
C:/py/defectURLS/app.py:6: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='C:/python/chromedriver.exe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/py/defectURLS/app.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='C:/python/chromedriver.exe')
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.141.0-py3.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.141.0-py3.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.141.0-py3.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.141.0-py3.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.141.0-py3.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Now, I'm pretty sure the smoking gun is:

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

This suggests to me that Selenium can find the webdriver okay as it is able to report back the webdriver version. The error seems to suggest that the chrome binary is not being located at the given location. But I am completely certain that this IS where Chrome.exe is located. I can launch chrome.exe directly from that path with no issues at all.

Would greatly appreciate a steer on what could be wrong.

Comment: try passing `options` instead of `chrome_options`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to locate the chrome binary *chrome.exe*

You need to consider a couple of facts as follows:

- Possibly you are using *Selenium Python Client v3.14.1* or *Selenium Python Client v3.141.0* and `chrome_options` is **deprecated** now. You need to use **`options`** though **`chrome_options`** still works.
- The *Key* `executable_path` must be supported with a *Value* as either of the following:

  - `r'C:\python\chromedriver.exe'`
  - `"C:/python/chromedriver.exe"`
  - `"C:\\python\\chromedriver.exe"`

Comment: There were three issues each of which became clearer following your reply.
1. My path to the Chrome binary was actually incorrect. The way Chrome was being packaged on my restricted desktop contained several instances of chrome.exe and wherre I was pointing to was not a clean binary.

2.  I needed to change to using 'options' instead of chrome_options. As well as that I needed a couple of other params.

3.  The version of webdriver I was using wanted to interact with Chrome 69 whereas I had Chrome 65 installed.

Many thanks!