# Trying to understand why Selenium cannot see Binary at '/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome' error despite solutions tried - using Heroku

Tags: django, selenium, heroku

I am trying to use Selenium and Heroku I've run into a common error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at '/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome'
```

I've come across this article as to why this may be happening:
[WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at C:/.../Chrome/Application/chrome.exe with ChromeDriver Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53131669/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-no-chrome-binary-at-c-chrome-ap)

I am using Selenium 3.141.0

It suggests that Chromedriver is unable to locate the binary chrome.exe. It also suggests to ensure that I am not using the deprecated option: `ChromeOptions()` and don't believe I need to use the keyword argument `executable_path` as I am launching it from Heroku where I would use `'/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome'` path. Other solutions I've come across suggests various different configurations and I feel like I have everything configured correctly but maybe not.

What else could be the reason that I am unable to get this to work?

> Buildpacks

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
```

> Heroku Config Variables

```
GOOGLE_CHROME_BINARY = "/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome"
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = "/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver"
```

> Options

```
class WebDriver:
def __init__(self):
    self.GOOGLE_CHROME_BINARY = config('GOOGLE_CHROME_BINARY')
    self.CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = config('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH')
    self.chrome_options = Options()
    self.chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    self.chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    self.chrome_options.binary_location = self.GOOGLE_CHROME_BINARY
    self.chrome_options.add_argument("headless")
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=self.chrome_options)
```

Any help even in just helping me understand what's going on better would be much appreciated